# Laravel 5 styles differ between environment

Tags: laravel-5, font-awesome

have a strange one! When working with my Laravel 5 app using font awesome, every icon shows up as it should when I am running locally with debug set to on.

When I turn off APP_DEBUG and set to false, one of my font awesome icons just does not show!? Very odd - any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Just one icon? The rest show up ok?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something weird with the href of the fontawesome css link tag.  Check your url or just use a cdn such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```